# streaming video device to windows with minimal delay

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming

Is it possible to somehow transfer video from phone to PC with minimal delay? For example, there is tokbox.com, but there, as I already checked, the delay is 1 second, which for my experiment is very huge. A delay of not more than 250 ms is required. It's real?

Comment: Are the two connected directly?

Comment: @AlexCohn, no, they are not in the same wifi network.

Comment: If you need a relay server, you are probably out of luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about live video from the camera built in to your device, then there are two methods you can use for sub-second streaming to PC.
Both methods involve installing a media server software on your PC and publishing live video to that media server. Compatible media servers: Wowza, Unreal Media Server, Flussonic, Flashphoner.

1. WebRTC publishing - here are some sample publishing webpages - try them on your device:

   https://secure28.securewebsession.com/umediaserver.net/demos/publish.html
   https://flashphoner.com/webrtc-streaming-demo/
   https://gist.github.com/theleon/fb83624f3de5c9076eb76c76dc638722
2. RTMP publishing - may be easier, as no browser security such as mixed content is involved: install some RTMP publishing app on your device, such as Larix Broadcaster, myCaster etc... - there are many of them.